# how to fetch result from two different database in a single mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have two different databases for a single website. One database is for the main data and another is for the temporary data to reduce the load on the main database.

**Mysqli Database Connection:**

```
$db1=new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','database1');
$db2=new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','database2');
```

**Mysql Database Connection:**

```
$dbLink1 = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('database1', $dbLink2);

$dbLink2 = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', true);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbLink2);
```

The below query is working fine in `mysql`. How can i run the below query in `mysqli`?

**Mysql Query**

```
SELECT sum(p.price) as sTotal, t.item_id as item_id
FROM database2.temp_cart as t, database2.temp_choices tc, database1.choice_price p
WHERE t.ses_mem= 1
AND t.item_id = 1
AND tc.item_id = 1
AND p.id = tc.choice_id
```

Comment: premature optimization with the huge big capital P

Comment: @e4c5 any help for the solution?

Comment: yes, stop this nonsense and use one database

Comment: You **don't** need 2 connections to connect to 1 server - even if you're querying different schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use other database as foregine key. your query is fine just use this query simple as you use other query

```
$db = mysql_connect($hots, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db('your_most_used_db', $db);

$q = mysql_query("
SELECT sum(p.price) as sTotal, t.item_id as item_id
FROM database2.temp_cart as t, database2.temp_choices tc,   
database1.choice_price p
WHERE t.ses_mem= 1
AND t.item_id = 1
AND tc.item_id = 1
AND p.id = tc.choice_id");
```